# How to change locations of drawn objects with user input

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, draw

I'm attempting to draw multiple fish (very simple ones), as many as the user specifies. But the circles aren't drawn in the proper places when the user specifies they want more than one fish to be drawn. All ovals are drawn, they just aren't in the right spots, so they no longer look like fish.

```
public class FishList extends JPanel {

static int fn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many fish would you like to draw? "));
static int w = 200;
static int h = 100;
static int x;
static int y; 
static int a = x + 20;
static int b = y + 30;
static int d = 50;
static int c = x + 195;

public FishList() {
  setPreferredSize(
        new Dimension(400,400));
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
  g.fillOval(c, y, d, h);
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.fillOval(a, b, 25, 25);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyFrame frame1 = new MyFrame("Drawing Fish");
  JPanel outer = new JPanel();

  for(int i=0; i<fn; i++){
     x = 0 + (i*(w+d+1));
     y = 0;
     FishList sPanel1 = new FishList();
     outer.add(sPanel1);

  }

  frame1.add(outer);
  frame1.pack(); 
  frame1.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JPanel`, by default, uses a `FlowLayout`.  `FlowLayout` also uses the component's preferred size to determine how to layout each component within the `Container`.

Failing to call `super.paint` is going to cause you serious issues.  In fact, you should use `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent`.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Components already have a sense of location and size, which you are ignoring.  The use of `static` variables in this context isn't going to help, because basically, each instance of your fish will be painted in the exact same location, as they will share the same value of the each of the `static` variables...

A better solution would be to generate a class that is capable of begin painted, which then paints the "fish".

These would be included inside a component capable of painting them, which you could then just add to a `Container` which is using a `BorderLayout`.

For example...

[image: Go Fish]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Fishies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Fishies();
    }

    public Fishies() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new FishBowel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FishBowel extends JPanel {

        private List<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public FishBowel() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                int width = random(20);
                int height = width;
                int x = random(200 - 20);
                int y = random(200 - 20);
                fishes.add(new Fish(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Fish fish : fishes) {
                fish.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static int random(int max) {

        return (int)(Math.round(Math.random() * max));

    }

    public class Fish {

        private Color color;

        private Ellipse2D fish;

        public Fish(Rectangle bounds) {
            this(new Color(random(255), random(255), random(255)), bounds);
        }

        public Fish(Color color, Rectangle bounds) {
            this.color = color;
            fish = new Ellipse2D.Float(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }

        public Ellipse2D getFish() {
            return fish;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(getColor());
            g2d.fill(fish);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be ungrateful, but I do not understand a lot of this. I'm only in my second computer science class, so this is lost on me. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @user2877117 Being a beginner is fine, but you've got to meet us half-way; what about the answer are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @user2877117 To achieve what you want, this is the simplest solution.  Other wise you will need to delve into creating your own layout manager, and if you think this example is overwhelming, then custom layout management is way more ... fun ...